# Lwt and database access

Tags: mysql, database, ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I can't get my database access work with lwt. Should I include it in a thread? How? Or make a new thread which returns a `'a lwt` value? If so, what to do with that value?

The same goes for `Printf.eprintf`, which also seems to be blocked by lwt. So I use Lwt_io instead. But why would lwt block regular io?

What I have is a simple db request like `Db.update session`. It is within an `Lwt_main.run main` function. All this is within a CGI script (should not matter, database access works fine until I start with the lwt commands).

I can give you more code if needed.

Regards
Olle

**Edit**

```
let main sock env = 
  (* code omitted *)
  Gamesession.update_game_session env#db game_session_connected;
  (* code omitted *)

Lwt_main.run (main sock_listen env)
```

**Edit 2**

This was the solution:

```
Lwt_preemptive.detach (fun () -> Db.call) ()
```

Comment: One important thing about Lwt is that when you start using it you  must use only Lwt. You must not use any blocking function with Lwt.

Comment: So what is a blocking function from Lwt's perspective? And how does it know?

Comment: @Olle, Have you cosidered using postgresql? It has nice examples about OCaml and Lwt. I can point out some.

Comment: Hi Kakadu, thanks for your tips. My codebase is using MySQL, so switching is not an option right now. At least it couldn't be done easily. Some examples could help still, perhaps? If you have any links, I'd be happy to read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Printf.eprintf` is not "blocked", it's just that the buffering parameters are changed and often messages do not display before the end of the program. You should try `eprintf "something\n%!"` (`%!` means "flush"), but yes it's better to use `Lwt_io`.

For the database, I don't know, you did not say which library you're using (at least the one called `ocaml-mysql` is not Lwt-friendly, so it may require using `Lwt_preemptive`).

#### Edit

Your:

```
Lwt_preemptive.detach (fun () -> Db.call) ()
```

This call creates a thread that, once executed, returns *immediately* the function `Db.call`. So, basically in that case `Lwt_preemptive.detach` does nothing :)

I don't know ocaml-mysql but if:

```
Db.call: connection_params -> connection_handle
```

you would have

```
let lwt_db_call connection_params =
  Lwt_preemptive.detach Db.call connection_params
```

Comment: Yes, its the ocaml-mysql one. I'll look into Lwt_preemptive!

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use `Lwt_preemptive`? My script just hangs if I use `run_in_main`.